# Is there an easy way to unpivot data like this with SQL?

Tags: sql

I don't really know SQL very well, but I've run into an issue where I receive data like this:

| Account Name | Tags |
| --- | --- |
| Demo | Tag A,Tag C,Tag E |

I need to write some SQL that will take the above table of data, and convert it over to this:

| Account Name | Tags |
| --- | --- |
| Demo | Tag A |
| ------------- | ---------------------- |
| Demo | Tag C |
| ------------- | ---------------------- |
| Demo | Tag E |

It needs to be pretty dynamic and non specific, because the list of possible tag names will be constantly changing. The only constant is that they will be a comma separated list and I need to break them out into separate rows of data like above.

Am I missing something obvious here in SQL that accomplishes the goal?

I am not really an SQL developer, so I don't have many details to share on what I've tried so far. More just Google searches not turning up any function that appears to do what I need.

Comment: Which database are you using? Support for this varies, but how easy/hard it is depends on which vendor. https://www.databasestar.com/sql-split-string/